# Store designation id in session

Tags: asp.net, authentication, login-control, loginview

When any user is login i show his/her name in upper right corner and in my application there is also a designations like manager,approve,director and i want when manager is login there is designation also display in upper right corner 
like this

```
john(manager)
```

i create sp like this

```
 create procedure [dbo].[spdesiname]
    @UserName nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50)
    as
    select Designation.DesigType from Userss inner join dbo.Designation on

    dbo.Designation.DesigID=dbo.Userss.DesigID where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password
    select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

and create function like this

```
public int spdesignname(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(db.ExecuteScalar("spdesiname", new object[] { UserName, Password }));
        }
```

and then call this function like this

```
int desginid1 = Convert.ToInt16(aa.spdesignname(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value));
             Session["UserDesignationName"] = desginid;
```

and then in master page i call session like this.

```
if ((Session["Login2"] != null) & (Session["UserDesignationName"] != null))
                {

                    WELCOME.Text = Session["Login2"].ToString() + "(" + Convert.ToString(Session["UserDesignationName"]) + ")";
                }
```

and then when i call this session in master page then it shows me incorrect password or username.

but i not works ,
How i done this ?

Comment: Please define the "not works", what error did you get...

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

if your session id made from **"Login2" + UserDesignationID**

```
if ((Session["Login2"]!=null) & (Session["UserDesignationID"] != null))
{
    //WELCOME.Text = Session["Login2"].ToString() + Session["UserDesignationID"].ToString();

    //TO DO : you need to find the designation based on Session["UserDesignationID"].ToString() and store into variable. i.e strDesignation

    WELCOME.Text = Session["Login2"].ToString() + strDesignation;
}
```

Comment: i store UserDesignationID in login purpose and i call this UserDesignationID in site master and when i try ur code it shows me error "the UserDesignationID does not exist in current context"

Comment: @user3134694 How are you storing your information in session in Master Page or login Page? Please share it

Comment: i add login page where is tore userdesignationid and i already post master page

Comment: @user3134694 I have updated answer, Please try it again.

Comment: hey it shows me like this when i run my app  ( john3) 3 is director

Comment: what is strDesignation?

Comment: how i display director instead of 3

Comment: @user3134694 Please store your designation into session variable like you did for UserDesignationID and use the session variable instead of strDesignation (strDesignation is just example)

Comment: @user3134694 Are you able to get UserDesignation from UserDesignationID ?